# Invoke specific event in a lambda from another lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sdk-nodejs

Hope your family and you are healthy.

I've below three events defined in my aws lambda#2.

```
/account/validate
/account/commit
/account/finalize
```

How can I invoke/call specific api/event from lambda#1.
We have nodejs code running in both the lambdas.

Before asking the question here I had surfed on internet and there was one article which says we should have separate lambda for each event or task. Is that so?

Can you guide me here? Your feedback would means a lot for me.

Comment: any idea on this issue please?

Comment: can you provide more information ?